# Magento ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/onyxclot/public_html/shell/abstract.php on line 144

Tags: php, error, session

I have checked my System.log to find im getting the above error, the below is the code from line 144, would any body be able to advise on how to resolve.

```
    foreach ($_SERVER['argv'] as $arg) {
        $match = array();
        if (preg_match('#^--([\w\d_-]{1,})$#', $arg, $match) || preg_match('#^-([\w\d_]{1,})$#', $arg, $match)) {
            $current = $match[1];
            $this->_args[$current] = true;
        } else {
            if ($current) {
                $this->_args[$current] = $arg;
            } else if (preg_match('#^([\w\d_]{1,})$#', $arg, $match)) {
                $this->_args[$match[1]] = true;
```

other errors include

> 2016-12-23T19:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/onyxclot/public_html/shell/abstract.php on line 144
>
> 2016-12-23T19:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/onyxclot/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508
>
> 2016-12-23T19:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/onyxclot/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 514
>
> 2016-12-23T19:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent  in /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 133
>
> 2016-12-23T19:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent  in /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 133

Comment: Please add more details from your logs (system.log and exception.log), there is missing some information.

Comment: these are all the errors in my system.log

Answer (score 0):

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Error arises due to empty or a non array so I suggest you check

```
$_SERVER['argv']
```

You add some condition to prevent this

Comment: are you able to kindly elaborate.

Comment: when you print `$_SERVER['argv']` do get data or an empty array ?